# 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function ..\assimp\vector3.inl

Tags: c++, opengl, ambiguous, assimp

Error

> error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function   c:\program files\assimp\include\assimp\vector3.inl

occures when I include 'scene.h' in main cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
#define MESH_FILE "cube.obj"
using namespace glm;
#include "common/shader.hpp"
#include "common/controls.hpp"
```

I can't get what does it conflict with?

Comment: does the `glm` namespace include a sqrt function?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I think yes, since it's math lib, but why do they conflict?

Comment: because `sqrt(var)` could refer to either the standard sqrt or the glm one

Comment: @RevanReborn: If `glm` does contain a `sqrt`, then dumping the namespace contents into the global namespace with `using namespace glm;` will cause a conflict with the one in the C library. It's never a good idea to pollute the global namespace like that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak  oh, damn.. sure..

Comment: How do I close this question?

Comment: @RevanReborn _'How do I close this question?'_ We can try for you, I'll cose vote it as OT if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a namespace **using-directive** in your .cpp file:

> ```
> using namespace glm;
> ```

This means that everything that is in the `glm` namespace becomes part of the "global" namespace; so you are *polluting* the global namespace.

So, there might be some form of conflict between the standard C `sqrt()` function (which lives in the global namespace) and your `glm::sqrt()`, which is "promoted" to a global `sqrt`.

You may want to remove the aforementioned namespace using-directive (and just add the `glm::` namespace prefix when you want to reference classes and functions in that namespace).